# How can I force Excel 2007 on Windows 7 to always open another instance of the application? 

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, multiple-monitors, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to be able to compare to large spreadsheets side by side...

Since you can not natively expand to all monitors I would like to have the two documents open in two instances.  These files are links on Sharepoint.