# How can I get Excel's undo/redo functionality to work in a more traditional *per window* manner (and not for the entire instance of Excel)?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, undo

This has been driving me crazy lately.  I'm not used to having having a program have a global undo/redo functionality (as in when I undo something, it will undo the last action in any currently open Excel window).  I'm used to having each open window having its own undo/redo list.  How can I get Excel 2007 to function more traditionally like that?

Comment: what *exactly* do you mean with "window" ? Separate files?

Comment: Yes, each window having a different file open.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel: how to undo in current file only?](http://superuser.com/questions/293044/excel-how-to-undo-in-current-file-only)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want separate undo/redo lists, open separate instances of Excel.

If you simply open multiple files by double-clicking, they're opened in the same Excel process and share the same undo/redo list. If you manually open multiple instances of Excel and then open your files in those instances, they don't share the undo/redo list.

For further details, you might want to check out:

- [How can I force Excel 2007 on Windows 7 to always open another instance of the application?](https://superuser.com/questions/279653/how-can-i-force-excel-2007-on-windows-7-to-always-open-another-instance-of-the-a)
- [How do I force excel (and other office products) to stop opening files in the same application?](https://superuser.com/questions/431061/how-do-i-force-excel-and-other-office-products-to-stop-opening-files-in-the-sa)

Comment: you can also achieve it [programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957334/trying-to-open-the-workbook-in-separate-instance/16959325#16959325)

Comment: As I have explained in http://superuser.com/questions/862263/how-should-i-create-multiple-instances-of-ms-excel-2013-in-win7-x64, I don't know why it didn't work for me.

Comment: `excel /x`  just run that from Run or from Start

Answer (score 2):

Unless operating on Excel files in different sessions I think we are stuck with a single undo list.

Edit that may (and quite possibly may not) help to explain the issue:

In Sheet1 `A1` enter `1`.
In Sheet2 `A1` enter `=Sheet1!A1`.
In Sheet2 `B1` enter `=A1+1`.
In Sheet1 `B1` enter `=Sheet2!B1`

Both sheets now look the same and the undo stack has:

```
Typing `=Sheet2!B1` in B1  
Typing `=A1+1` in B1  
Typing `=Sheet1!A1` in A1  
Typing `1` in A1
```

Separating this out into the two sheets:

```
Sheet1                         Sheet2  

Typing `=Sheet2!B1` in B1
                               Typing `=A1+1` in B1
                               Typing ` Sheet1!A1` in A1
Typing `1` in A1
```

Unwinding just the Sheet1 part of the history is equivalent to deleting the contents of Sheet1!A1:B1. Try that and the values in Sheet2 will change. So even a separate undo history for each sheet/workbook/window would not achieve ‘isolation’.

Excel may (quite sensibly, in my view) be assuming that there is some basis for having two workbooks/windows open in the same session – that there is reason to expect interaction between one and the other. If such interaction is not required there is always the option to open workbooks in a different session.

At all frequent use of different sessions (eg extended desktop) may soon illustrate some of the advantages of operating within a single session.

Comment: I fear you may be right.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a cop-out and only applies to newer versions of Excel, but if you’re willing to open Excel via your browser (at https://portal.office.com), each workbook will be in an individual tab with its own Undo/Redo history.

May be acceptable if you’re in a work environment without the ability to manage shortcuts, etc.